# Populating a dropdownlist control and display "select one" as default

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, drop-down-menu

I have the code block below, how do I display "select one" as the top selected value?

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" DataTextField="StudentName" DataValueField="StudentName"></asp:DropDownList>
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ddl_connStudentProfile %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [StudentName] FROM [StudentProfile]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Do you have a student called "select one", or do you need to add that as an item to the top of the list?

Answer (score 1):

Use a list item

```
<asp:ListItem Text="Select One" Value="-1"></asp:ListItem>
```

And use this property `AppendDataBoundItems="true"`

combining both

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" 
     DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" DataTextField="StudentName" 
     DataValueField="StudentName" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Select One" Value="-1"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" 
      ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ddl_connStudentProfile %>" 
      SelectCommand="SELECT [StudentName] FROM [StudentProfile]">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add this default item manually and set `AppendDataBoundItems` to `true`:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" 
        AppendDataBoundItems="True"
        DataTextField="StudentName" 
        DataValueField="StudentName">
    <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="0">select one</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: Is it required `Selected="True"`?

Comment: @Șhȇkhaṝ: yes, if you want it to be selected(_"as the top selected value"_). You could also select an item which comes from the database but add this static item anyway. Then you have to use `SelectedIndex`,  `SelectedValue` or `SelectedItem` or loop all items and set the `Selected` property programmatically.

Comment: I think default the first element get selected by default and the first will be `select one`?

Comment: @Șhȇkhaṝ: you seem to be right, if no item is selected the first items is selected by default. But don't you want it to make explicit instead of always looking at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.dropdownlist.selectedindex(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: Not just want to confirm on this :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use following to make required as selected. You can write this in page_Load event.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    DropDownList1.SelectedIndex = DropDownList1.Items.IndexOf(DropDownList1.Items.FindByText("select one"));
}
```

Comment: This could work if there is a student called "select one", but I hope there isn't. You also need to wrap your line in `if (!Page.IsPostBack) { ... }` otherwise the value will get reset any time a postback is triggered.

Comment: Yes, this could be, as OP told that , `"select one"` text needs to be selected.